# How to sort a list by values (from a matrix) and break ties by first minimum, then by 2nd minimum, etc.?

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say I have a matrix where each column is associated with a value. For example:

```
A = [[ 7.41,  5.44,  4.75,  0.35,  6.50],
     [ 9.59,  5.68,  8.72,  7.88,  5.04],
     [ 3.61,  2.79,  3.36,  4.05,  5.81],
     [ 3.35,  4.52,  0.35,  5.47,  3.35],
     [ 8.69,  3.79,  9.86,  1.90,  7.80]]
```

and column 0, column 1, column 2, column 3 and column 4 have values `C = [3, 3, 3, 2, 3]`, respectively.

Now, I would like to sort the columns of `A` by their values, i.e., the column that has the highest value is the first, etc. I will get:

```
S = sort C in decreasing order
S = [4, 2, 1, 0, 3]
```

but there are many ties in `C` so I need to break these ties by the 1st minimum. If there is always ties, break them by 2nd minimum, etc. Otherwise, break ties arbitrarily.

In my example, I should break ties between columns `4, 2, 1` and `0` since they have the same values in `C`. (NB. column `3` comes last whatsoever because it has the lowest value and is unique.) So let's see the ith minimums in columns `[0, 1, 2, 4]`.

The 1st minimum in columns `[0, 1, 2, 4]` are `M1 = [3.35, 2.79, 0.35, 3.35]` and the 2nd minimum are `M2 = [3.61, 3.79, 3.36, 5.04]`. (In this example, we only need to look up to 2nd minimum.) We have:

- Column `2` has the minimum value in `M1`, it comes first.
- After column `2`, comes column `1` because it has the second 1st minimum.
- Now, column `0` and column `4` have the same 1st minimum. We have to see their 2nd minimums `M2`. Because `3.61<5.04`, column `0` comes before column `4`.

Hence the final sorted columns are

```
Final = [2, 1, 0, 4, 3]
```

How do I achieve this sorting in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the columns by descending value and sorted column. That way the columns will be compared by their smallest value first, their second-smallest value second, and so on:

```
# transpose to list of columns
a_trans = list(zip(*A))  # Py3
a_trans =      zip(*A)   # Py2

# zip columns with indeces and values
cols_c = list(zip(range(len(C)), C, a_trans))  # Py3
cols_c =      zip(range(len(C)), C, a_trans)   # Py2

# sort by desc value and sorted column
cols_c.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], sorted(x[2])))
```

Now you can construct the sorted original matrix:

```
# extract columns and transpose back to rows
A_sort = list(map(list, zip(*(c for i, val, c in cols_c))))  # Py3
A_sort =      map(list, zip(*(c for i, val, c in cols_c)))   # Py2
[[4.75, 5.44, 7.41, 6.5, 0.35],
 [8.72, 5.68, 9.59, 5.04, 7.88],
 [3.36, 2.79, 3.61, 5.81, 4.05],
 [0.35, 4.52, 3.35, 3.35, 5.47],
 [9.86, 3.79, 8.69, 7.8, 1.9]]
```

or just the ordered indeces:

```
indeces = [i for i, val, c in cols_c]
[2, 1, 0, 4, 3]
```

If you do not mind having an iterator over tuples or sth. likewise, you can omit some of the casting calls.

Some references on:

- [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)
- [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)
- [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)
- [argument unpacking (`*` operand)](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-parameter)

Comment: Thank you. Can I have the indices sorted instead of the matrix sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort based on the weights given in list `C` and then break ties with the least two minimums in each column using [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
import heapq
import pprint

A = [[ 7.41,  5.44,  4.75,  0.35,  6.50],
     [ 9.59,  5.68,  8.72,  7.88,  5.04],
     [ 3.61,  2.79,  3.36,  4.05,  5.81],
     [ 3.35,  4.52,  0.35,  5.47,  3.35],
     [ 8.69,  3.79,  9.86,  1.90,  7.80]]

C = [3, 3, 3, 2, 3]

A_by_cols = zip(*A) # tranpose A so we can sort by columns
f = sorted(enumerate(A_by_cols), 
           key=lambda x: (-C[x[0]], heapq.nsmallest(2, x[1])]))

pprint.pprint(f)
# [(2, (4.75, 8.72, 3.36, 0.35, 9.86)),
#  (1, (5.44, 5.68, 2.79, 4.52, 3.79)),
#  (0, (7.41, 9.59, 3.61, 3.35, 8.69)),
#  (4, (6.5, 5.04, 5.81, 3.35, 7.8)),
#  (3, (0.35, 7.88, 4.05, 5.47, 1.9))]
```

You can then recreate the final list of lists by stripping off the indices and transposing:

```
A_final = list(zip(*(x for _, x in f)))
pprint.pprint(A_final)
```

---

```
[(4.75, 5.44, 7.41, 6.5, 0.35),
 (8.72, 5.68, 9.59, 5.04, 7.88),
 (3.36, 2.79, 3.61, 5.81, 4.05),
 (0.35, 4.52, 3.35, 3.35, 5.47),
 (9.86, 3.79, 8.69, 7.8, 1.9)]
```